# SelectOneMenu userinput action - onclick

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Prerequisites:

- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 5.2
- Glassfish 3.1

Story:
I've got a selectOneMenu which can be edited by the user but also can change its value when loading the data.

Problem:
I need to figure out if the user actually choose an item or if the item changed because of some other reason. The onchange event is thrown in both cases.

Question:
Is there some way to figure out if it was a userinput or some onclick event for a selectOneMenu?

Implementation:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenu" value = "#{myBean.value}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{myBean.label}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
  <f:selectItems value = "#{myBean.items}" var="item"
  itemLabel = "#{item.label}" itemValue="#{item}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: What is 'the other' way? Via javascript? Then set a param in that javascript and add that to e.g. the submission to the server

Comment: @Kukeltje The shown selectOneMenu is in the cells of a column in my datatable which displays data depending on what is choosen in another selectOneMenu

Comment: Yes, so? If it is loading and nothing is actively selected, there is nothing selected. So I still totally fail to see the problem and what you are trying to solve. Sorry.

Comment: @Kukeltje if the displayed data of the datatable change, the value of the selectOneMenu within the datatable changes, too. This causes a change event to be fired. My problem is that i need to detect, if the change event was fired by a user choosing something, or if it was some other cause

Comment: I think you are trying to work around a [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/). If the the value (server side) only changes from the ui if an action is performed by something on the client. If you change the list behind the selectOneMenu on the server, the value of that select does not change by something from the client-side. Never... So please create an [mcve] that demonstrates your original problem with original code

Comment: @Kukeltje what i am trying to do is to figure out if an item of my selectonemenu was picked by a user. There are multiple other possibilities what could change the value of my selectonemenu but i don't care about them. I want to run an action "onclick".